# Use last element of Observable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I have an Observable that gets some data from Firebase (using AngularFire2), something like this (I do not need the stream of changes, only the last one):

```
this.items = this.af.database.list('/items').take(1);
```

Then later (in another function normally called when the data has arrived) I want to work with the result, for example like this:

```
this.items.last().do(items => {
  console.log('items from server',items);
});
```

But that does not work (it does not result in anything in the console log).

How can I work with the latest result from the Observable?

Comment: Consider using `BehaviorSubject`, which has `getValue` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observable is cold (has no subscription), you need to add one:

```
this.items.last().do(items => {
  console.log('items from server',items);
}).subscribe();
```

or even better, replace the `do` with `subscribe`

Comment: Can I then do something like `this.items.subscribe().filter(.....).map(.....)`? I want the result to continue to be an Observable.

Comment: The subscribe comes last. so it is `this.items().filter().map().subscribe()` and not only that you can, this is the rxjs way to do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to your observable. Also, your take(1) will only grab the first item. I would assume you have more than one item in your "/items".

[Here](http://rxmarbles.com/#take) is a great site on how observable operations work.

Comment: Actually `take(1)` grabs all the items (at that point in time). Thanks for link.

Comment: Yup, you're definitely right, my bad! haha. Looking at this stuff too early!